# Has Akatsuki searched for phosphine in Venus?

Tags: venus, astrobiology, akatsuki

The Akatsuki orbiter is never mentioned in articles about the phosphine discovery, does it have the capability to detect it and has it tried?

Comment: Good question! No spacecraft has the capacity or budget to carry every instrument needed to cover every possible method of examining a celestial object.

Answer (score 3):

I think it does not have the ability to detect it.  What [was observed](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-020-1174-4) (or may not have been observed now) was a rotational transition at $267\,\mathrm{GHz}$ or about $1.123\,\mathrm{mm}$.  Akatsuki's instruments are all in or around the visible spectrum: it has instruments which work from $\sim 250\,\mathrm{nm}$ to $\sim 10\,\mathrm{\mu m}$ I think, probably with gaps (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_(spacecraft)#Instruments)).  I couldn't work out whether it had a spectrometer of some kind for one or more instruments: I assume it does however.

Of course there may be *other* ways of detecting phosphine, but if there were I suspect there would be a frenzy of activity of trying to do that from Earth.  It's possible that there are things that would be masked by the atmosphere however.